# VBA increasing dynamic range in VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm having trouble with setting properly dynamic range for VLOOKUP which should be increasing by 58 with each loop (I have 96 different ranges). VLOOKUP table is in other ("Gefco") sheet. The error I'm getting is:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Code:

```
Sub vlookup_rates()

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Long
Dim rr, dupa As Range
Dim ws, wws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook


c = 1
a = 2
b = 59
d = 2
e = 59

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Gefco")
With ws
Set rr = Range(Cells(d, 4), Cells(e, 8))
End With

Set wws = wb.Sheets("Waberers")
wws.Activate

    Do While c < 97
        Cells(4, a).Select
        Cells(4, a).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A$4;" & rr.Address & ";5;0)"  <-ERROR

        c = c + 1
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
        d = d + 58
        e = e + 58

    Loop
End Sub
```

I think range is somehow wrongly defined but I can't crack it.
Please halp.

Thanks!

Comment: What line is giving you the error? Is the the Formula line?

Comment: You need to set `rr` inside the loop or d&e will never increase, I don't see "b" being used, you could probably delete it. `Cells(4, a).Select`  you could probably delete this line as well.

Comment: edited for error line

Comment: Look at this as well..`With ws
Set rr = .Range(.Cells(d, 4), .Cells(e, 8))
End With`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some of the things you are doing wrong:

```
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long
Dim e As Long
Dim rr, dupa As Range '// rr will be dimensioned as variant
Dim ws, wws As Worksheet '// ws will be dimensioned as variant
Dim wb As Workbook


c = 1
a = 2
b = 59
d = 2
e = 59

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Gefco")
With ws
Set rr = Range(Cells(d, 4), Cells(e, 8)) '// This range refers to the ActiveSheet, not the 'ws' object.
End With

Set wws = wb.Sheets("Waberers")
wws.Activate '// No need to activate a sheet if you've set a reference to it.

    Do While c < 97
        Cells(4, a).Select '// No need to select a range, you can access it's properties and methods directly.
        '// The below formula will work if 'rr' is on the ActiveSheet, however the "rr" range has been set, and so it's address will never change unless you change the range that "rr" is actually set to
        Cells(4, a).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A$4;" & rr.Address & ";5;0)"

        '// b, d & e are not used in the loop - so updating their values serves no purpose.
        c = c + 1
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
        d = d + 58
        e = e + 58

    Loop
End Sub
```

and here's an example of how you could do this:

```
Dim counterInt As Integer, d As Integer, e As Integer
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet, ws2 As Excel.Worksheet

d = 2
e = 59
Set ws1 = Sheets("Gefco")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Waberers")

    For counterInt = 1 to 96
        ws2.Cells(4, counterInt).Value = Application.Vlookup([A4], ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(d, 4), ws1.Cells(e, 4)), 5, False)
        d = d + 58
        e = e + 58
    Next counterInt

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
```

Comment: now this gives error: the item with the specified name wasn't found. Indicating line with formula.

Comment: @5yp10n What is the error, and on what line does it occur?

Comment: @5yp10n someone beat me to it - but the `Cells()` method wasn't qualified - try above edit.

Comment: works great, just edited slightly: ws2.Cells(4, counterInt + 1).Value as it was reffering to looking value and look up table to ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(d, 4), ws1.Cells(e, 8)). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers you can also use the R1C1 notation in the formula:

```
wws.Cells(4, a).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R1C4, R" & d & "C4:R" & e & "C8,5,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Good alternative, however the OP uses `;` as delimiter

Comment: Good point - had to change them to commas so I could test on my computer.  I take it it's just a case of changing them back to a ';' for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit of solution for reference.
Thanks to above solution of SOofWXLS I was able to fill all the table from B4 to CS61 with dynamic ranges of VLOOKUPS, it fills cells row after row:

```
Sub vlookup_rates_2()
Dim rowInt As Integer, counterInt As Integer, d As Integer, e As Integer
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet, ws2 As Excel.Worksheet

d = 2
e = 59
Set ws1 = Sheets("Gefco")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Waberers")

For rowInt = 4 To 61
    For counterInt = 1 To 96
        ws2.Cells(rowInt, counterInt + 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(rowInt, 1), ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(d, 4), ws1.Cells(e, 8)), 5, False)
        d = d + 58
        e = e + 58
    Next counterInt
    d = 2
    e = 59
Next rowInt

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```